# Buscar una clase css con .find

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy iterando unos colores con php y el código es este:

```
<div class="colores_conf_producto">
   @foreach ($colores as $item)
     <div class="info_color_conf @if ($loop->first) activeProducto @endif @if ($item->stock == 0) noStock @endif" data-color="{{ $item->color }}">
        <img src="{{ $item->foto }}" alt="">
        <h3>{{ $item->color }}</h3>
     </div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

La primera opción del bucle lleva una clase que se llama `activeProducto`, entonces tengo que guardar en una variable de JavaScript el primer color elegido.

Lo hago del siguiente modo:

```
window.onload = function() {
    obtener_primeros_valores();
};


var color_elegido = "";

function obtener_primeros_valores(){
    color_elegido = $(".colores_conf_producto").find('.activeProducto').data("color");
    $('#color_elegido').html(color_elegido);
};
```

Esto me funciona bien.
Si os dais cuenta en la iteración hay una condición `@if ($item->stock == 0) noStock @endif`, esto es para que si el stock es "0", añadir una clase CSS donde lo opacito y además hago que no se pueda pulsar.

Entonces la duda es, a través del `foreach`, ¿se puede hacer que si el primer resultado tiene `stock = "0"` seleccione el siguiente?

Comment: Hola Miguel, el titulo de la pregunta no se corresponde con la pregunta en el cuerpo. Para mi lo que necesitas es agregar `activeProducto` al primer producto con `stock` y eso lo deberías hacer en el `template` con `Blade`. ¿Te interesa una respuesta así?

Comment: Hola @Marcos perdona si lo hice un buen detalle, si correcto lo que comentas es lo que busco, que se seleccione el primer elemento del foreach que `stock == 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar `activeProducto` al primer producto con `stock`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Agregar una variable (`$isActive = false`) para saber si ya agregamos un "activo"
- Al recorer el arrelgo de `$colores`, analizar si:

  - Si `$item->stock == 0`, entonces agregamos el estilo `noStock`
  - En caso contrario y si todavia no agregamos un activo:

    - Modificamos el valor de la variable `$isActive = true`
    - Agregamos el estilo `activeProducto`

#### Ejemplo:

```
<div class="colores_conf_producto">
    @php
        $isActive = false;
    @endphp
    @foreach ($colores as $item)
        @php
            $styles = "info_color_conf";
            if ($item->stock == 0) $styles .= " noStock";
            else if (!$isActive) {
                $isActive = true;
                $styles .= " activeProducto";
            }
        @endphp
      <div class="{{ $styles }}" data-color="{{ $item->color }}">
        <img src="{{ $item->foto }}" alt="">
        <h3>{{ $item->color }}</h3>
      </div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/5cb42f45-1131-4154-9e74-a8791c83f4fa)

Comment: Gracias @Marcos funciona a las mil maravillas, gracias por ayudarme a aprender algo nuevo ;)